# lesskey: add alt+right keybinding to less

Tags: escape-characters, less, terminal-emulator, pager

I used `cat -vte` to see what escape codes my terminal emulator sends when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>:

```
❯ cat -vte 
^[[1;3C
```

Then I added this escape code to my lesskey file `~/.less`:

```
\e[1;3C  forw-scroll
```

Finally I launch `less`:

```
LESSKEY=~/.less less some_file
```

But pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> does not work.

Comment: I have a partial solution, but first I should know your `less` version.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity `less 590`.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

[The manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html#LINE_EDITING) states:

> You may define your own less commands by creating a lesskey source
> file [...]
>
> If the environment variable **LESSKEYIN** is set, less uses that as
> the name of the lesskey source file.  Otherwise, less looks in a
> standard place for the lesskey source file: **On Unix systems, less
> looks for a lesskey file called "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lesskey" or
> "$HOME/.lesskey"**. [...]
>
> **Previous versions of less (before v582) used lesskey files with a
> binary format, produced by the lesskey program. It is no longer
> necessary to use the lesskey program**.

And the definition of the variable `LESSKEY`:

> LESSKEY
> Name of the default lesskey binary file. (Not used if "$LESSKEYIN" exists.)

So as I understand you don't need to define the variable `LESSKEY` since your version is after 582. Just having your plain text `~/.lesskey` file is enough. (A side note, environment variables have to be defined by `export VARIABLE=value`).

---

Now I've managed to make it work <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> with this configuration in the `~/.lesskey` (after using the `lesskey` command, but you don't need it):

```bsh
#command
^[[ forw-scroll
```

...but it also works with the other arrow keys.

---

What you can do is to bind a character instead of an arrow key, remembering that you can be overriding an existing functionality.

Let's say for example you choose the character `m` since `^[\kr` doesn't work. First find the octal value with the command:

```
$ echo m | od -b | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2
155
```

Then in your `.lesskey`:

```bsh
#command
^[\155 forw-scroll
```

Now when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> you will have the result you are looking for.

---

This is untested for `less` version 590, since mine is 551.

Comment: What do you get when you press `alt+right` in `cat -vte`? I guess your escape codes differ from mine.

Comment: @HappyFace I get the same, but the thing is that configuration the file doesn't understand that kind of notation, see [http://man.sourcentral.org/debian-buster/1+lesskey](http://man.sourcentral.org/debian-buster/1+lesskey).